# Docker issues and errors

Tags: docker, ubuntu-22.04

i tried a lot of time to enter the command **docker ps -a** in terminal i am getting this error this error:

my Operating system: "ubuntu 22.04"

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/ali/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

but when i try this command again with root access the command works fine but the command not working without root access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour.

If you don't want to type `sudo docker` all the time you can either add your user to the `docker` group but I don't recommend that (it is not secure) or you can create an alias like `alias docker='sudo docker'`. Your user need to be in the sudoers list, obviously.